# Image with 100% width in Media Queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have an image with 100% of width inside a div with a width of 820px. When I scale down the image to a screen size of an iPad and an iPhone 5, the image scales down to, but in that sizes I want the image to be 100% of the screen size width.

I already tried to use a width of 100% in the Media Queries, but the image never scales to a full width.

Which is the best to make an image responsive with a full screen width in tablets and smartphones? Considering that I'm using a grid that have a max-width of 960px (the Skeleton grid: http://www.getskeleton.com/)

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using media queries properly, image **will** scale to 100%, but relative to the parent element. So, take care that parents of image get 100% on small resolutions.

Comment: So if the parent image is a div with a width of 820px and this div have a parent div with a width of 960px, I use a media querie to define the width of these 3 elements with 100%?

Comment: Something like that. Because if you want to set image width to 100% of screen size, every parent must have width of 100%. If width of block elements is not defined, then width is 100% by default.

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't work. The html structure is something like this: <artice><div (width(960px)><div (width820px)><img></div></div></section>

Answer (score 0):

An image of width 100% will be the 100% width of its parent.  So yes if the parent is 820px wide, then that's how wide the image will be.  If the parent is 960px wide then that's how wide the image will be.

So you will need to change the width of the parent div in the media query (probably in the same one that you are setting the image to 100% width).

Comment: So considering that I have this structure in hmtl: <section><div><div><img></div></div></section>, and that only <section> doesn't have a width defined, I need to change the width of the 2 div's and of the img in the Media Query? I change the width ou max-width also?

Comment: That's correct.  Usually when I go down to a mobile size, my layout becomes fluid.  Basically all my divs and imgs are set to 100% width.  You can change the max-width if you'd like, it really depends on what you want it to look like.